# Loading conditions that refer to another table - Phpactiverecord

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I think I'am hitting a limitation with phpactiverecord, but need clarification:

```
$data = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'still_in_contest' => 1,
         'contest_month'   => $month,
         '`genres`.`id`'   => $genre, # THIS is the issue.. and an awkward "hack" that 
                                      # I was hoping would work..
     )
     'include' => array('song' => array('artist','genre')),
     'joins'   => array('
           LEFT JOIN songs 
               ON (songs.id = contest_submissions.song_id)
               LEFT JOIN genres 
                   ON (genres.id = songs.genre_id)',
     ),
```

Is it impossible to simply add something like `genres.id` into the query?

[`phpactiverecord`](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) is setting up the query as:

```
WHERE `contest_submissions`.`genres`.`id`=?
```

If it is is there some other way to still benefit from autoloading with another similar query without doing everything on my own?

EDIT:
My solution right now has been to just modify the core of phpactiverecord's SQLBuilder class to not append the name of the table if there's a dot in the key...

EDIT2:

I tried your solution Nanne, and it iddn't work out.  Phpactiverecord ends up prepending the table name to everything. :(

```
$genre = 1
    if($genre)
       $data['conditions']['genres.id'] = $genre;
     $data['conditions']['contest_submissions.still_in_contest'] = 1;
     $data['conditions']['contest_submissions.contest_month'] = $month;
```

It worked out previous because I kept my hack in.  Did I format the condition incorrectly?

EDIT3:

yes.. yes I did format it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.
I've not tested it because I didn't have time to recreate your tables, but it is what I currently use: it is just a different syntax to use in your conditions.

```
$join   = "LEFT JOIN songs ON (songs.id = contest_submissions.song_id) 
           LEFT JOIN genres ON (genres.id = songs.genre_id)";
$models = \Models\YourModel::all(array( 
                  'joins'     => $join,
                 'conditions' => array('contest_submissions.still_in_contest = ? 
                                    AND contest_submissions.contest_month = ? 
                                    AND genres.id = ?',
                                 1,
                                 $month,
                                 $genre)));
```

(I hope I got the tablenames and the amount of arrays/brackets right :)

Comment: Genius ;]!
I'm glad you're here to help so much with phpactiverecord =P
Are you one of the developers?   I'll try it and remove my changes to the core classes to see what happens

Comment: Nope, but an active user (and active SO user). I'm hoping to get some mass in this topic on SO, as the forums of phpAR aren't visited by too many people :) (and I like SO better as a QA Platform)

Comment: I see the changes that need to be made, but I'm going to be stubborn about my hack because I do want to be able to easily add dynamically needed fields to the condition with an array as opposed to string concats and an array push.  This is indeed the correct answer to the question though!